# SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) - Does it delete source data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, migration

Pretty much my question is the one in the title - does the SSMA tool delete or alter source data in the MySQL server to be converted?

Hopefully I'm right in my assumptions that it does not delete or alter the source data, and only migrate a copy of it to the new database. I'm just seeking some form of clarification before I proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, I just solved this by creating a quick test MySQL database and testing the migration across. As far as I can tell, it does **NOT** delete or alter any of the source data.

Thanks for reading though! ^_^